# What kind of statistical test is appropriate for the following example?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation, pca

I ran an experiment varying the temperature and the quantity of chemicals added for the removal of 4 contaminants (A, B, C and D). The data obtained from this experiment was (in R):

```
temperature <- c(rep(20,4),rep(30,4),rep(40,4))
chemicals <- rep(seq(0,30,10),3)
contaminant_A <- c(9,22,25,28,35,50,57,78,86,94,97,100)
contaminant_B <- c(0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 5,11,11,13,18,18,21)
contaminant_C <- c(68,57,53,50,44,38,36,34,31,29,25,24)
contaminant_D <- c(39,68,35,32,53,69,69,60,35,30,43,36)

DF <- data.frame(temperature,
                 chemicals,
                 contaminant_A,
                 contaminant_B,
                 contaminant_C,
                 contaminant_D)
```

[image]

I'd like to use a statistical test (or some statistical tests) to answer questions like:

- Is the temperature or the quantity of chemicals the most relevant variable of the process?
- Are the removals of the contaminants related?

I was thinking of using a PCA, however I'm not sure.

If there is a graphical way to explain it, that would be great.

**EDIT 1:**

As Izy suggested, I used the GLM for all contaminats:

```
> glm(contaminant_A~temperature+chemicals)

Call:  glm(formula = contaminant_A ~ temperature + chemicals)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  temperature    chemicals  
   -65.1750       3.6625       0.8033  

Degrees of Freedom: 11 Total (i.e. Null);  9 Residual
Null Deviance:      12030 
Residual Deviance: 327.1    AIC: 81.72
> glm(contaminant_B~temperature+chemicals)

Call:  glm(formula = contaminant_B ~ temperature + chemicals)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  temperature    chemicals  
     -18.23         0.80         0.21  

Degrees of Freedom: 11 Total (i.e. Null);  9 Residual
Null Deviance:      604.9 
Residual Deviance: 26.77    AIC: 51.68
> glm(contaminant_C~temperature+chemicals)

Call:  glm(formula = contaminant_C ~ temperature + chemicals)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  temperature    chemicals  
    91.1250      -1.4875      -0.3833  

Degrees of Freedom: 11 Total (i.e. Null);  9 Residual
Null Deviance:      2090 
Residual Deviance: 99.71    AIC: 67.46
> glm(contaminant_D~temperature+chemicals)

Call:  glm(formula = contaminant_D ~ temperature + chemicals)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  temperature    chemicals  
   59.51667     -0.37500     -0.05667  

Degrees of Freedom: 11 Total (i.e. Null);  9 Residual
Null Deviance:      2615 
Residual Deviance: 2498     AIC: 106.1
```

Using contaminant A as example, can I say that the temperature is more relevant than the quantity of chemicals because the coefficient is bigger?
What value of these results informs about the relation like a R^2?

Comment: Have you considered a general linear model (glm family in R)? e.g. glm(contaminant~temperature+chemicals). Do you expect any interaction between the effect of temperature and the effect of quantity of chemicals? Your knowledge here may be able to inform what subset of possible tests/models you might want to use. For your second question, have you checked if the removal of various contaminants is correlated, as a starting point?

Comment: PCA $\ne$ statistical test. (And much of what I have seen published which attempts to incorporate tests into PCA is rife with violations of the i.i.d. assumption.)

Comment: @Izy first, the expected was that the increase of the temperature improve the removal, but the data didn't show this. I uses de GLM for the contaminants (look at the original question EDIT)

Comment: I will only suggest that you use some numerical and graphical methods to get an idea which variables are associated with which others. I tried a couple of things with functions in the base of R. At first glance, it seems that regression methods may be useful. I will use Answer format to show a couple of things I tried. I don't understand the intended role of Chem, so I didn't use it.

Comment: There is no conclusion that numbers/methods give you that you can't put meaningfully into a plot.  This is because there are 5 ways to rephrase a mathematical idea: formulae, tables, figure/graph, words, and flowchart/graph.  It is immensely valuable to double-check every conclusion you get to by plotting it.  My old retired core-comp mgr used to call them "GRC's" or Gross Reality Checks.

Answer (score 1):

Not an Answer. Continuation of comment:

```
MAT = cbind(Temp, a, b, c, d)
cor(MAT)
           Temp          a          b           c           d
Temp  1.0000000  0.9446208  0.9199987 -0.92024370 -0.20741843
a     0.9446208  1.0000000  0.9705441 -0.95711450 -0.20573950
b     0.9199987  0.9705441  1.0000000 -0.92154735 -0.29544696
c    -0.9202437 -0.9571145 -0.9215473  1.00000000  0.07196594
d    -0.2074184 -0.2057395 -0.2954470  0.07196594  1.00000000
```

It seems that `d` isn't significantly correlated with anything else.
I think you are right that a graphical approach may be helpful, at least at the start. As suggested by correlations near $\pm 1$ above, it seems there are some nearly
linear relationships.

```
pairs(MAT)
```

[image]

Maybe based on some of this, you will want to clarify your
experiment and its goals by editing your Question (not with Comments which may be missed). Meanwhile, I will let someone who isn't booked up for the evening make
suggestions for interpreting your regression and perhaps trying
additional regression models.